# Ionic 3 local notifications only trigger the last one

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I'm trying to schedule delayed notifications if I use schedule(here one notification ) and scheduled it one by one only the last  one is triggered . If I use schedule(notifications[ ]) it also work for the last one in the array . How could I solve this , please help ??

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I've used Math.random() function to provide a different id . Although the ids different mathematically , the plugin sees it the same id .